# Python Google API get() vs get_media()

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am attempting to use Python to access some files stored on a Google Team Drive. I have figured out the functionality to download files, but am running into a mysterious issue when attempting to get metadata

If I execute the following:

```
myfileid = 'thegooglefileid'
self.service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
data = self.service.files().get_media(fileId=myfileid).execute()
meta = self.service.files().get(fileId=myfileid,fields="*").execute()
```

"data" returns as expected allowing me the info to download my files as I expect. "meta" returns with a HttpError 404 indicating it can not find the file (which it in fact found in the line above).

I know this issue can occur with incorrectly set authorization, but my authorization is set such that I expect this to work

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
```

Any ideas why the file is visible to one part of the API but not the other ?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct reason of error, it seems that in your script, ``myfilename`` instead of ``myfileid`` is used as ``fileId``.

Comment: Thanks. I had edited this from real code to remove and actual file id and my modification was poor. I have edited the original to clarify

Comment: Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice about it. I'm sorry for this.

Comment: Hi. How have you found a way to download the file?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, an important point is this is accessing TeamDrive. In the specific case of the get call in which "meta" is retrieved, the API needs to be informed that it is using a TeamDrive

The following code works once I figured this out

```
myfileid = 'thegooglefileid'
self.service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
data = self.service.files().get_media(fileId=myfileid).execute()
meta = self.service.files().get(fileId=myfileid,fields="*",supportsTeamDrives=True).execute()
```

Interestingly, get requires this parameter while get_media functions fine without it